# Access to property of other object in parent level

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have 2 objects coming to template:

```
foo: {
  some: {
    use: "item1"
  },
  thing: {
    use: "item3"
  }
},
bar: {
  item1: {...},
  item2: {...},
  item3: {...}
}
```

Using **{{#each}}** helper I switching every **foo**'s property. Inside of each we have **use** property contains text value of property in **bar** object that I want to use.

How can I get access to them?

```
{{doSomething ../bar.[this.use]}}
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: What about proper bracket notation, `../bar[this.use]`?

Comment: I've used syntax like described [here](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html)

Comment: I see. Nevermind then.